# Convert String to character if character not match will replace until it matches

Tags: java, arrays, regex, sqlite, character

```
/* search from database */
            String value = fname+"_"+mname+"_"+lname+"_"+bdate;
            DataBaseHelper dbh = new DataBaseHelper(SecondActivity.this);
            String holder = dbh.search(value);


            /*convertion of string search to array */
            char[] chars=holder.toCharArray();
            Character[] characters=new Character[chars.length];

                try{
                for(int x=0;x<chars.length;x ++){
                    characters[x]=chars[x];

                    if(characters[x].equals('A')){
                        characters[x]++
                    }else{
                        //replace function the move to the next character

                    }
```

im stuck and i dont know what should i do next. I want to replace the character if it does not match the Name from the database.
For example:
from database:
fname 
Robin
User input:
rodin
since it did not match it will then replace the un-matched character until it matches the name Robin.

Comment: You want all the characters to be the letter "A"?

Comment: Why not just use the name from the database? I don't see what the comparison you are doing gains you.

Comment: Not exactly. only the match character if not replace it with other letters until it is correct. Sorry for the confusion i just starter and ended with 'A'.I will make it from A to Z @RealSkeptic

Comment: i want it to be user friendly even if he typed it wrong the system will replace the wrong letters until it matches every letter. I cant do heavy algorithms yet im just a beginner so ill have to hard code it. @PeterLawrey

Comment: @RobinBernardo what is the difference between "Robin" where you replaced the characters which were wrong and the original string "Robin" which has all the right characters from the start?

Comment: The variable `holder` seems to already have the proper name, right? So why do you bother to replace the value in the original name? Use the `holder` instead of `value` from this point forward.